# Logstash mix output when using two config files

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using logstash 1.5.6 in Ubuntu.

I wrote two config files in the `/etc/logstash/conf.d`, specifing different input/output location:

File A:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "api"
    path => "/mnt/logs/api_log_access.log"
  }
}
filter {
  ...
}
output {
  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        protocol => "http"
        index => "api-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        template => "/opt/logstash/template/api_template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
      }
  }
}
```

File B:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "mis"
    path => "/mnt/logs/mis_log_access.log"
  }
}
filter {
  ...
}
output {
  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        protocol => "http"
        index => "mis-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        template => "/opt/logstash/template/mis_template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
      }
  }
}
```

However, I can see data from `/mnt/logs/mis_log_access.log`  and `/mnt/logs/nginx/dmt_access.log` both shown in index `api-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` and `mis-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`, which is not I wanted.

What's wrong with the configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logstash reads all the files in your configuration directory and merges them all together into one config.

To make one filter or output section only run for one type of input, use conditionals:

```
if [type] == "api" {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So for the output part there is no need to change?

Comment: The output sections can also be "protected" by conditionals.

Comment: The elastic guys [plan to get rid of type attribute](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch#sthash.GPJLwX6q.dpbs) and it also won't apply if you already have type field in your source (it doesn't override). So I advise using tags or add_field instead.

Comment: @BornToCode That _type_ attribute is a different sense to this one - it's a discriminator between document types in the same Elasticsearch index, whereas this is a type attribute carried within the Logstash pipeline. This one may eventually appear as a _type_ field in the Elasticsearch document, but the actual Elasticsearch document _type_ ( specified using output { elasticsearch { document_type => "..." } } - which doesn't automatically get populated from the Logstash _type_) is stored with an underscore prefix.

Answer (score 2):

It better handle filters with input type

File A:

```
input {
   file {
     type => "api"
     path => "/mnt/logs/api_log_access.log"
     }
 }

   if [type] == "api" {
     filter {
      ...
     }
   }
```

File B:

```
input {
 file {
    type => "mis"
    path => "/mnt/logs/mis_log_access.log"
  }
 }

   if [type] == "mis" {
     filter {
      ...
     }
   }
```

File C: output.conf

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

working with logstash 5.1

Comment: Thanks for your tips.

Comment: The elastic guys [plan to get rid of type attribute](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch#sthash.GPJLwX6q.dpbs) and it also won't apply if you already have type field in your source (it doesn't override). So I advise using tags or add_field instead.

Comment: In my case, in logstash 7.11.1, I needed to put the suggested "if" statement inside "filter" and "output" block due to a parsing error during logstash startup